# SQL Server Time data type not compatible with Excel?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, time, type-conversion

Problem:

Importing time data from SQL Server (2014, 2016) via VBA `CopyFromRecordset()` method is not recognized as time but as `Standard` type.

Example:

SQL query which is used in Excel VBA

```
SELECT TOP 100
    [CreationDate],                                     -- Works as expected Datetime; data type of this field is DATETIME 
    CAST(CreationDate AS DATETIME) AS CreationDate2,    -- Works as expected Datetime
    CAST(CreationDate AS TIME(0)) AS CreationTime       -- In Excel the type is Standard and not Time as it should be.
FROM 
    [StackOverflow2013].[dbo].[Comments]
```

VBA code:

```vb
Sub TimeImport()
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim SQL As String

    Const ConnStr  As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=PC\\MSSQLSERVER2014; Initial Catalog = StackOverflow2013; Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    'SQL see above
    Conn.Open ConnStr
    RS.Open SQL, Conn

    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset RS

    RS.Close
    Conn.Close

    Set RS = Nothing  
    Set Conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

After importing if i enter a cell in the time column in Excel with F2 and press enter, the it change the data type into time correctly. Just changing the format of the cell to time does not work however.

If I import the data record by record and convert the time field to date using `CDate()` function then it works. However it is not an option for me due to bad performance of row by row processing.

Did anyone face this issue before and what was the solution?

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following workarounds which work:

1. After importing the data I copy the data from the data range to the same range so to say.

If the data is in `A1:D100` the VBA code would look something like this:

```vb
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D100").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D100").Value
```

2. Instead of `CopyFromRecordset()` I save the recordset data into an array by using the GetRows function of the recordset object and then put the array into the spreadsheet like this:

   ```vb
   Sub TimeImport2()

       Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
       Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
       Dim SQL As String

       Dim myArr As Variant
       Dim RecCount As Long

       Const ConnStr  As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=PC\\MSSQLSERVER2014; Initial Catalog = StackOverflow2013; Integrated Security=SSPI;"

       ' SQL see above

       Conn.Open ConnStr
       RS.Open SQL, Conn

       myArr = RS.GetRows
       myArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myArr)
       RecCount = UBound(myArr)

       ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D" & RecCount) = myArr

       RS.Close
       Conn.Close

       Set RS = Nothing  
       Set Conn = Nothing
   End Sub
   ```

The good thing about the second approach is that you can get the fields and rows of the recordset individually and process them like this:

```vb
.Range("A2:A" & RecCount) = Application.Index(myArr, , 4)
```

It is still mysterious why Excel does not recognize the Time data type of SQL Server or gets the data type corrupted by the `CopyFromRecordset()` method?